# Validate phone numbers with specific prefixes/country codes in sql

Tags: sql-server, excel, validation

I have entries of cell phone numbers that come into the database and most of the numbers start with 27, 0, +27 and 0027. So I constructed the query below and it works just fine. The only problem is I recently found out that there are some numbers that don't contain any of the prefixes.

When a number comes in without the prefix it always has 9 digits for example 823744777 so I am assuming I can use 9 digits as the first point of call in my validation. How can I alter the query below to cater for such numbers as well(catering for 9 digit values that do not start with 0, 27, 0027 or +27)

```
IF(@cellNumber2<> '' AND ((@cellNumber2 like '27%' and len(@cellNumber2) !=11) 
OR (@cellNumber2 like '0%' and len(@cellNumber2) !=10) 
OR (@cellNumber2 like '+27%' and len(@cellNumber2) !=12)
OR (@cellNumber2 like '0027%' and len(@cellNumber2) !=13)))
BEGIN
    IF ((SELECT ISNULL(ClientId,0) FROM tbl_invalidNumbers
    WHERE ClientId = @ClientId) = 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tbl_invalidNumbers(ClientId, cellNumber2)
        VALUES(@ClientId, @cellNumber2)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE tbl_invalidNumbers
        SET cellNumber2 = @cellNumber2
        WHERE ClientId = @ClientId
    END
    UPDATE tbl_tempDataTable
    SET cellNumber2 = null WHERE ClientId = @ClientId
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL Server's enhanced `LIKE` operator:

```
IF(@cellNumber2<> '' AND (
    (@cellNumber2 LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]') OR
    (@cellNumber2 LIKE '27%' AND LEN(@cellNumber2) != 11) OR
    (@cellNumber2 LIKE '0%' AND LEN(@cellNumber2) != 10) OR
    (@cellNumber2 LIKE '+27%' AND LEN(@cellNumber2) != 12) OR
    (@cellNumber2 LIKE '0027%' AND LEN(@cellNumber2) != 13))
)
BEGIN
...
```

The extra check I added whitelists any input consisting of any 9 digits.  Otherwise, one of your other existing checks would have to pass in order for the `BEGIN` block to get hit.